# Python: csv.reader on mmap file works incorrect

Tags: python, csv, mmap

I need to parse a rather big csv file with Python. For this purpose I use csv (file contains quotes), and I want to parallel this process using multiprocessing. Every process will read only it`s lines from mmap file object. But on implementing this approach I faced the next problem (I know about python with statement, this is just a demo):

```
import csv


f = open('temp', 'r+b')

reader = csv.reader(f)
reader.next()

f.close()
```

Ouputs:

```
['1000415037534300', '2013-07-14 13:25:13.000000', 'request', '281', 'Camino', 'LG']
```

and that`s right, but consider this example:

```
import csv
import mmap


f = open('temp', 'r+b')
m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)

reader = csv.reader(m)
reader.next()
reader.next()
reader.next()

m.close()
f.close()
```

prints

```
['1']
['0']
['0']
```

In other words, it reads by one byte from the file.
I have to use mmap beacuse there is no another way to allow several processes to use the same file.
The question is, why csv.reader behaves so wierd with mmap object? mmap object has the same api as standart python file object, so csv.reader shoult work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `iter` with readline to read each line:

```
 reader = csv.reader(iter(m.readline, ""))
```

If you iterate over `m` you will get one char at a time so passing m to reader will exhibit the same behaviour

Comment: Is there any reason why mmap implemetns iterator this way?

Comment: I suppose the fact you can slice the mmap object like `m[:n]` to get n bytes it makes sense that it iterates in bytes not lines or `m[:n]` would give you n lines as opposed to n bytes